# When to use prompt=login and how to handle it? OpenID Connect

Tags: authentication, openid-connect

I need to implement `prompt=login` in OIDC provider, but I really don't have idea how to do it.
Should we log out and display login form to re authenticate user? It seems bad idea for me because in this case any client is able to logout any user (it seems very strange for me).

What's more, I don't see any advantages of using `prompt=login`. After all, you always can use `prompt=none` to check if user is still logged in, and if is then verify received userid from `id_token` with currently logged user in client.

So how OIDC provider should handle `prompt=login` and when `prompt=none` is useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROMPT PARAMETER**

To use the prompt parameter, just include it in your authentication request:

```
GET https://login.example.com/oauth/v2/authorize?
client_id=my-client&
redirect_uri=https://www.example.com&
prompt=login ...
```

The `prompt=login` option is often used when logout is problematic, eg in some mobile scenarios. In this case an app can simply remove its tokens, then redirect with this parameter set.

The [max-age](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) parameter is also related, to force re-authentication when a certain time has passed, rather than implementing logout.

Another use case might be a redirect for a currently logged in user, to get tokens with a higher privilege, eg a payment scope.

**DELEGATIONS**

When a particular user and client authenticate, the authorization server creates a delegation, for the client_id and subject. An SSO cookie is a pointer to all such delegations the user agent has created.

So given these delegations, and a prompt parameter ...

- User 1 and Client A
- User 2 and Client A
- User 1 and Client B

... it should only impact the current client and user, and update that delegation. Whether this works entirely correctly may depend on the provider though.

Comment: 1. So while I'm using authorization_code with PKCE without SSO then is prompt=login useless for me? 2. How OIDC provider can handle `prompt=login` parameter? As I mentioned, scenario where any client can logout any user seems strange to me (see my question), but maybe is this valid scenario?

Comment: In most normal apps the prompt parameter isn't used, unless you need to work around usability issues. I added some more info on delegations.

Comment: Do you think it's good to store these delegates in cookie at identity provider (so this cookie contains all clients to which user has logged in) or rather you would to store these delegates at the server side of identity provider (e.g. in database)?

Comment: A database usually. I would not try to develop an OIDC provider myself though. Instead, use an open source or low cost system where someone else has put tons of time working out this type of detail and getting it reviewed. Instead aim to have a good understanding of how it works at an application level.